# How to create and display XML through Javascript/PHP/

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, xml-parsing

I have some javascript objects that represent the XML that i want to create.
I need a simple way to create/ generate XML, and then somehow hand it over/ show it to the user in a clean way (structurized, like in the screenshot example).

I've been experimenting and researching but haven't yet foudn what i am looking for.

Current test code:

```
            function exportXML(){
var XML = document.createElement("div");
var Node = document.createElement("testing");
Node.appendChild( document.createElement("testingOne") );
Node.appendChild( document.createElement("TestingTwo") );
Node.appendChild( document.createElement("TestingThree") );
XML.appendChild(Node);

//alert(XML.innerHTML);
xmlWin = window.open("","xmlWin","width=800,height=600");
xmlWin.document.write("XML: \n" + XML.innerHTML);
            }
```

xml example:

```
-<station stationNr="WP006">

  -<definitionstat>

      <admtyp>A</admtyp>

      <responsible>SIEMENS</responsible>

      <bildnam>B12</bildnam>

      <stattyp>T</stattyp>

   </definitionstat>

 </station>
```

What i would like to have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create XML:

```
$xml            = new \DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");  
$xml->formatOutput  = true;
$xml_data       = $xml->createElement("Element_Container","Container Value");  
$xml_data       = $xml->appendChild($xml_data);
$xml->saveXML();
$xml_status->save($xml_file_path);
```

To display in formatted way:

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file_path);
  foreach ($xml->children() as $key => $child)
  {
        // Your formatted output here...
  }
```